# Java How to Serialize a list of items in generated csv file?

Tags: arrays, csv, serialization, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a program A— that generates a random list of students and outputs to a comma separated text file.
The output looks like:

```
Name, Age, Sex, Ethnicity
Ann, 22, F, White
Mark,19,M,Asian
```

I have program B- that reads that generated CSV file above and, calls a method sort() and outputs the list of students sorted based on age to a new CSV file, output looks like:

```
Mark,19,M,Asian
Ann,22,F,White
```

It will sort all students in a list of however many students are generated.

Now the question is how do I use serialization to obtain the result of sorted students without parsing and sorting the text itself?
In other words, I need to write a class that will serialize the deserialise the whole database of students. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please add some more context to your question (although it might be rejected, as this seems like homework). What have you tried so far? What language are you trying to use? What's the sorting criteria?

Comment: Does that mean your program B just processes the text rather than reading the CSV data into objects? If by serialization you do mean reading and writing CSVs, you could use something like Apache Commons CSV which reads and writes CSVRecord classes, and you could write a Comparator for CSVRecord that sorts by age to use with the standard collection sort methods.